# Unable to query using date timestamp in mongodb atlas data api

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

Unable to query using date while passing through mongo data api. I would like to query the database to find fetch all entries at the time

The below code returns empty document

The sample db :

```js
[{
  sensorId:'1231541',
  sensorTimestamp:'2022-01-28T20:14:26.223+00:00'
}]


await superagent.post(`${url}/action/${body.action}`)
       .send({
        dataSource: 'Cluster0',
        database:'testDB',
        collection: body.collection,       
        filter: body.filter,
        sort: body.sort,        
      });


const config = {
  action: 'find',
  collection: 'testCollection',
  filter: {
    sensorId: '1231541',
    sensorTimestamp: {
      $gte:  new Date('2022-01-28T20:14:26.223+00:00'),
      $lt: new Date('2022-01-28T20:33:16.324+00:00'),
    },
  },
  sort: {
    name: 1,
  },
};
```

Comment: Is `sensorTimestamp` stored as a date object in the collection?

Comment: yes it is stored as date

Comment: Are any errors reported?  Why do you sort on `name` if `name` is not in the doc?  If you execute the same query from `mongosh`, do you have the same experience?

Comment: My `javascript` knowledge is very limited, including its use with `MongoDB`, but I'm wondering if `sort` is allowed there with a `find` query.

Comment: I need to fetch docs in between those timeline given, so the sensorTimestamp must be the option for filtering,

Comment: I don't get any errors instead it returns empty document.

Answer (score 0):

You must query dates in millis, not tje string representation of that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33281044)